# Cannot Open Database, Login failed for user. For one specific Application in IIS all others work

Tags: sql-server, iis, windows-authentication

I am stumped! I have one server that has 16 applications inside Default Web Site for IIS.

I am only getting this error on one of the applications.

I have two connections strings, One that is the default connection that is actually working for it, and another connection string for a reporting connection to run reports in the system.

I have even restored from a backup of the problem connection database to my Test Database, and it works perfectly.

Here is my connection string

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=Capital;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Instance=false"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="ReportingConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=Captial;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True; User Instance=false; "
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool is a window user for that database

Owned Schemas & Database role memberships are
db_datareader
db_datawriter
db_dbowner

In IIS Manager I have Anonymous Authentication status set to enabled, and Application pool identity selected as the Anonymous Authentication Credentials.

I have ASP.NET Impersonation set to Enabled.

In the wwwroot folder's security I have DefaultAppPool as user with the following allowed
Read & Execute
List folder contents
Read

Please let me know if you need any other information, and I appreciate any help. I have tried all of the ideas posted in other posts related to this, but to no avail! I would expect the Default connection to fail as well.

Comment: What is the actual error message? My guess is that the user you are connecting with does not have connection permission to the database in question.

Comment: If you are using Impersonation then IIS is not connecting using `APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` it is actually connecting using the Windows login of the user who connected, who we're guessing doesn't have the right permissions.

Comment: Have you looked closely at your connection strings? One has `Initial Catalog=Capital`, the other `Initial Catalog=Captial`, i.e.: `Capital` != `Captial`

Comment: I think as community members discussed. Perhaps you need to grant permissions to the user. Also, I think you can test setting Integrated Security=false. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.